# Is Split View implementation reuired for iPad PRO or optional?

Tags: ios, ipad

We have no use for split view in our app, but it should run on iPad PRO.
Are we forced to use/implement split view capability anyway?

Comment: Absolutely not, it is up-to you whether you want it or not. But if you are developing an universal app, make sure you create an exclusive iPad UI design(storyboard) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the UIRequiresFullScreen key to YES in your plist.